# What does “the hardware” a Japanese moviemaker took home after being awarded the Jury prize at Cannes Film Festival mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Japan Times (May 28) reported that Hirokazu Koreeda, movie director won the Jury Prize at 2013 Cannes Film Festival.
The article titled, “Director Koreeda wins Jury Prize in Cannes begins with the following sentence:

> “Director Hirokazu Koreeda’s “Soshite Chichi ni naru (Like father,
>   like son)” has become the latest Japanese moviemaker to take **the
>   hardware** home, after he was awarded the Jury Prize at this year’s
>   Cannes Film Festival. Koreeda’s movie a story about two couples, whose
>   babies were switched at birth, is the first Japanese work to receive
>   the prize since the late Rentaro Mikuni’s “Shinran: Shiroi Michi” was
>   honored the honor in 1987.”

According to Oxford English Dictionary, Hardware mean;

1. tools, machinery, and other durable equipment:
2. the machines, wiring, and other physical components of a computer or other electronic system:.

Cambridge English Dictionary also defines ‘hardware’ as:
the physical and electronic parts of a computer, rather than the instructions it follows.

I’ve never learnt the case of “Hardware” which I understand only in contrast to ‘software’ being used in such a way referring to the prize. What does a Japanese movie maker took the “hardware” home?

Can 'hardware' normally be used in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, "hardware" is a euphemism for a trophy, often used in headlines like [UCLA baseball finally adds hardware to national championship trophy case](http://www.ncaa.com/news/baseball/article/2013-06-26/ucla-baseball-finally-adds-hardware-national-championship-trophy-ca) or [Nice hardware: National championship trophy impresses](http://staugustine.com/stories/010807/sports_trophy.shtml). It likely relates to the use of "hardware" to mean small metal goods, similar to the "hardware bag" containing screws that comes with furniture you have to assemble yourself and the use of "hardware" as slang for carryable metal weapons.

Comment: David Schwartz. Thanks. At a second look, I found the definition of ‘hardware as 5. an award (as a trophy, medal, or cup) given in a sports competition, on top of pretty familiar 1. ware (as fittings, cutlery, tools, utensils, or parts of machines) made of metal. 2. major items of equipment or their components used for a particular purpose. 3. military equipment. 4. the physical components (as electronic and electrical devices) of a vehicle or an apparatus (as a computer) in Merriam Webster English Dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it's interesting - I'm sure people below a certain age find it rather demanding to look for meanings (especially semi-metaphorical) other than the computer-related one. People of my age grew up with the hardware of 'hardware stores' and 'hardware departments' (which both still exist, but may now be called DIY stores / departments) being the only known sense: tools, nails, nuts, bolts, galvanised tubs, clothes lines and pegs, candles... 'Silverware' is the usual popular term for trophies, because they often contain / look like they contain silver.